# Rails 4: After updating an attribute post a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

How do I go about posting or rendering a message after updating an attribute to reflect the changes?
(I couldn't find anything online in respect to this task)

For example: Once a user updates the ticket status there will be a message posted in the comment section reporting "Ticket has been closed". (No flash message, but a permanent one).

tickets_controller.rb

```
def open 
   @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
   @ticket.update_attributes(:ticket_status, "closed")
   redirect_to ticket_path
end
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you heard of the rails `flash` ? have a google for how that works in rails and it'll help you out :)

Comment: @TarynEast: He has writen that he doesn't want flash

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma oops, missed that bit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the message in database if you want it to persist. Say for ex- There is a ticket raised (Ticket model) and someone closes it. The attribute on backend will update attribute status for ticket model.

```
 def update
   tkt = Ticket.where(id: 1)
   tkt.update_attributes(status: 1)
 end
```

If this is an ajax call, you can send a response data with message like "Ticket closed " and display it accordingly on html page in the success callback of ajax call. If it's a server call, refresh the page and use the status attribute from Ticket model to create the message.

You can use some enums like

```
{0 => "Ticket Open", 1 => "Ticket closed", 2 => "Ticket in progress" }
```

In case messages are not generic and every time some more customization is required, better to create and save the entire message as an attribute in the related model and no need to have enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session for this purspose.

```
def open 
   @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
   @ticket.update_attributes(:ticket_status, "closed")
   session[:close_message] = "Ticket has been closed"
   redirect_to ticket_path
end
```

After that diaplay it in the view like

```
<%= session[:close_message] %>
```

but make sure to clear the session like `session[:close_message] = nil` after displaying the message to free the memory

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I was wondering...Is there a way not to set it up in a session? I would like to keep it as a persistent message that is not changed by multiple changes in open -> close.

Comment: you can do one thing more , pass the message in the paramerter like redirect_to ticket_path, message: 'Ticket has been closed'  & read it the ticket path controller like @message = params[:message], & then display it the view

Comment: but this is not a good thing to pass the message in the parameter , I would suggest to use flash messages for these types of messages

Comment: I see.. is there a way to have flash messages without them going away after a page refresh?

Comment: Do you want to display the same message multiple times?, if yes, then create a flag fiels in the database, & set it true when u update the data, & write the condition like , if flag  then @message = "your messge" & display it in view

Comment: My answer is also similar to the above :)